# UIActivityViewController - order of items

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I Have an array of items I want to share. How can I force to have a specific order? For example:

```
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[text, image, image, audio]
```

The order of the items in the array does not work for the order in the shared app.

Answer (score -1):

You can't force a specific order of shared items, the shared items isn't the issue anyways, that's just telling the delegate what UIActivity applications to populated based off the array of information you provided. Your trying to reorder the applications supported in the `UIActivityViewController`. You can exclude certain items that are built in like camera roll, Facebook etc using `excludedActivityTypes` to omit certain share points from populating that aren't relevant to your shared item.
Your best bet at this moment, is to either subclass `UIActivityViewController` where you can create custom icons etc for your `UIActivityViewController`, but this won't allow you to reorder the applications supported. However you have a lot more options for customizing by subclassing:
`canPerformWithActivityItems:` `prepareWithActivityItems:` etc. You might be able to play around with this and see if you can customize the activities displayed in a subclass an example to subclass :

```
- (UIActivityViewController *)subclassedActivityViewController {
CustomActivity *customActivity = [[CustomActivity alloc] init];
FacebookActivity *facebookActivity = [[FacebookActivity alloc] init];
MessageActivity *messageActivity = [[MessageActivity alloc] init];
MailActivity *mailActivity = [[MailActivity alloc] init];

NSArray *applicationActivities = @[customActivity, facebookActivity, mailActivity, messageActivity];
NSArray *activitiesItems = @[@"A string to be used for customActivity", @"A string to be used for FacebookActivity", @"A string to be used for MessageActivity" etc];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activitiesItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

// Removed activities you don't want displayed
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                                 UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                 UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                                 UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                                 UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                 nil];

return activityVC;
}
```

However if this doesn't circumvent your issue then you will have to create your own `UIActivityViewController` until they implement this feature.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP asked.