# UIActivityViewController Add Option

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I use a UIActivityViewController to either airdrop or email a data file to another user.  This works just fine.  But I now find I need to create an option in the UIActivityViewController to save the file in the local filesystem (filename, etc. is known so user won't have to specify it).

So, I'm just trying to find a concise example of how to customize the UIActivityViewController to add a choice like, "Save to Archive" to the UIActivityViewController, and to execute a selector when it is touched.

Can this be done and can anyone point me to an illustration on this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You just have to subclass it. [This should get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28015045/2353523) I'm on my iPhone so can't search Apple docs for a working example. Will update when I get to a computer

Comment: Thank you.  I'm going to work with this.

Comment: Ok sorry about the vagueness. I'm sure there are hundreds of better examples out there then the one I led you to  but I feel like it's a duplicate question so I'm shying away from giving a complete answer. Again, working from an iPhone but I'll double check in the morning

Comment: No, this is fine.  In fact, if you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as such.  My real question was how to go about it and you answered it.  Thanks...